# Different characters, same ASCII code?

Tags: mysql, varchar, encoding

I have this query that throws two results:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id like 'nm041033%'
```

1. nm0410331
2. nm0410331

And this slightly different query that throws only one result:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id='nm0410331'
```

1. nm0410331

I tried to check the ASCII of the last character and got the same:

```
SELECT id,ascii(substr(id,9,1)) FROM table1 WHERE id like 'nm041033%'
```

1. nm0410331 49
2. nm0410331 49

I guess it is a rare encoding problem. How can I solve it?

PS: The field `id` is a **primary key**. The charset is `latin1_general_ci`, and the values were inserted using PHP `utf8_decode()`.

---

**UPDATE:** I changed the charset to `ascii_general_ci`, and now this query gives me zero results:

```
SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id='nm0410331'
```

However, those two ids are not the same yet. If I use `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` I get two rows.

PS: The last character isn't the number you can type with the keyboard.

Comment: `SELECT id, HEX(id) FROM table1 WHERE id like 'nm041033%'`?

Comment: @Akina Thanks for the nice insight. `HEX()` shows me an extra '0A' byte at the end of the string that was not visible. I tried `UPDATE table1 SET id=REPLACE(id,UNHEX('0A'),'');` and didn't work. I will try further.
set idpelicula=replace(idpelicula,unhex('0a'),'')

Comment: I'm surprized. 0x0A at the end of a record value must cause linebreak in output, so the output table on the console become visually broken. You couldn't not see this...

Comment: I'm ashamed. Using the _PHMyAdmin_ GUI I couldn't note it. I guess using that should be a sin in this exchange xD

Comment: @Peter Mortensen, thanks for the edited enhancements.

Comment: My usual 'visual' query to find excess whitespace: `select '#' + field + '#' from table` - maybe helps someone :)

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to the insight of [Akina](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/150107/akina), who suggested to use `HEX()` to check the field, I found an extra '0A' byte at the end of one of the values.

After removing the primary key constraing (to avoid the temporary duplicate id), I used:
 `UPDATE table1 SET id = TRIM(TRAILING UNHEX('0A') FROM id);`
And was able to solve it.

PS: For future googlers, using `SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE id like 'nm0410331%'` could make me note my silly problem too...

Answer (score 2):

Ideally you shouldn't have to "clean" the data - you should fill them in using TRIM - and using a proper escape-function ... if a linebreak could sneak in there - quite possibly a single quote as well .. and hello, welcome to SQL-injection....

Comment: That's true. In this case Is not an open system, just data analysis for science purpose.